# Animated number counter c# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I would like to implement an animated number counter in c#.
There is a lot of material available for JS - CSS and java , but not much for c#.
I tryed the following code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i<value; i++)
        {
            lblCounterDis.Text = i.ToString();
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
```

Using this script i only freeze the application for some seconds.
Should i use some BackgroundWorker? Any more advanced method?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) …?

Comment: you can use the [timer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use await/async to prevent freezing

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await UpdateLabelAsync();
}


private async Task UpdateLabelAsync()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Please note that I used .net 6 for this example.
Not sure if it also works with .net framework.

Comment: It takes 17 seconds to complete with 1ms delay -  Task.Delay(1) - How can i solve this? If i increase the step then i will not get the correct number in the end